# How to call a function within a child widget?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a child widget that has an audio player and a button, when I press that button it calls the `playAudio()` method which plays the audio as expected since everything is contained within one file.

However, the child widget is nested within a parent widget and I don't know how to call the same `playAudio()` method from the parent widget.

How can I get the `Parent Play Button` in the parent widget to call the method within the child widget?

Also: I read that flutter encourages `setState`, in which case, how can one use `setState` to trigger the audio?

**PARENT WIDGET**

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:phonica/audio_test/child.dart';

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ParentWidget();

  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 300.0,
              height: 100.0,
              color: Colors.green,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: TextButton(
                child: Text("Parent Play Button"),
                onPressed: () => {}, // <-- Call child widget's playAudio()
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ChildWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**CHILD WIDGET**

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
ChildWidget();

  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  final audioPlayer = AudioCache(fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer());

  playAudio() {
    String audioFile = "audio/words/alive_0.mp3";
    audioPlayer.play(audioFile);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300.0,
      height: 100.0,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: TextButton(
        child: Text("Child Play Button"),
        onPressed: () => {playAudio()},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use provider (https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or bloc library.

Comment: Can you explain in more details?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/provider-pattern-in-flutter/

Comment: in this example you can access 'Counter' class any where.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your parent widget by **GestureDetector()**, then use the **onTap** to call the function. See below

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              // Toggle light when tapped.
              _lightIsOn = !_lightIsOn;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow.shade600,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            // Change button text when light changes state.
            child: Text(_lightIsOn ? 'TURN LIGHT OFF' : 'TURN LIGHT ON'),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: This won't work for me since I want to call the function via code and not only via user input. How can I do that?